# Displaying a card on top of a clip-path shape

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, clip-path

I'm looking to design a website kind of like the [duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com/)'s website with a rounded background and cards laying on top of the curve:

[image]

But what I have right now looks something like this where the clip-path cuts off the cards:

[image]

The code looks something like this with the css of the section :

```css
 .two {
        background-color: #ff6b6c;
        clip-path: ellipse(99% 66% at 48% 77%);
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <section class="two" style="margin-top:250px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        Featured
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        Featured
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You could convert the `clip-path` to a pseudo `::before` element and use it as a background with z-index. This way you wont modify the content.

Comment: could you give an example of a pseudo `::before` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice you to use background elements as pseudo (::before) elements. If you convert it to a pseudo element it will render in the background.

```css
 .two {
        position: relative;
 }

 .two::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #ff6b6c;
        clip-path: ellipse(99% 66% at 48% 77%);
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <section class="two" style="margin-top:250px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        Featured
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        Featured
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: @ph-quiett if you find this answer helpfull, please accept the answer to we can close the question :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are expecting.

```
.two {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        background-color: #ff6b6c;
        clip-path: ellipse(99% 66% at 48% 77%);
    }

<section style="margin-top:250px;position: relative;">
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Featured
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Featured
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```